# What does this mean in shell script? ${1+"$@"}?

Tags: shell

I have no knowledge of shell script. Can anyone explain what does this mean?

```
exec python2.7.1 "${BASEDIR}/../foo/foo.py" ${1+"$@"}
```

I think that this will execute the foo.py file inside the foo folder. But, what is the meaning of `${1+"$@"}`?

Comment: I can't think of any compelling reason to use that over just `"$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

`$@` is one of the builtin variables used by the shell to deal with command-line arguments to a script.  Within the script:

`$0` is the command that launched the script

`$1` is the first argument

`$2` is the second argument, etc...

`$*` is the list of all arguments including the command that launched the script

`$@` is the list of all arguments not including the command that launched the script.  So, if the whole command was:

```
myscript.sh glorf frolg flerg
```

Then `echo $@` will echo:

```
glorf frolg flerg
```

I'm not sure what the ${1...} thing is about.  It doesn't seem to change the behavior.  It still just echoes `$@` .  Basically what your script does is pass all its arguments on to foo.py.

Okay, thanks @Wander Nauta.  Looking [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), you can see that `${1+"$@"}` means, "if `$1` exists, pass `$@`, otherwise pass nothing."

Comment: The `${...+...}` is [alternate value syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMALTV). It passes an empty string if no arguments are given.

Comment: `echo $@` is very bad practice -- consider `printf '%s\n' $@` vs `printf '%s\n' "$@"` with any interesting contents (like `set -- 'hello' '*' "cruel world"`, setting `$@` to a value with both whitespace and glob characters) to showcase why: Without the quotes, the shell string-splits and glob-expands contents before passing them through. Thus, with `$@` you get a list of all the filenames in your current directory printed, and the space between `cruel` and `world` becomes a newline, but with `"$@"` you get everything properly preserved as entered.

Comment: Also, while the explanation by @WanderNauta is otherwise correct, it's not "otherwise pass null string" -- a null string would be `''`; with the quoting precisely as given by the OP, this is passing no arguments at all if `$1` is unset, thus *not* passing a null string in that scenario.

Comment: That reference actually uses the term "null string" to say what gets passed.  But I've updated my answer to say "nothing".

Comment: If you want to prove that, run `set -x` to enable debugging in your shell, and compare `set --; echo ${1+"$@"}` to `set -- "hello world"; echo ${1+"$@"}` or `set -- ''; echo ${1+"$@"}`.

Comment: The "reference" given is the ABS, which hasn't been maintained for years and is well-known for frequent inaccuracies (but, alas, has been around for ages and thus has lots of Google juice; it's the w3schools of bash references). If folks want an actually *good* reference, they should be using either the bash man page, the bash-hackers wiki, the wooledge wiki, or (where relevant) the POSIX spec.

Comment: I'm going to be very pedantic and say that `$@` is *not* a variable.  `@` is the name of the variable. `$@` gives the contents of `@`, using the unary operator `$`.  In addition, the difference between `$@` and `$*` is not as you state - they differ only when enclosed inside `" "`, and not in the way you describe, otherwise their values are the same.